# Opening urls with Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Is there some sort of library available for Scheme to open/read URLs? I'm using the ypsilon implementation, if it matters.

Searching Google for anything related to Scheme is most unhelpful, and even though I've tried to be very specific and creative in my searches I come up with absolutely nothing.

I can't be the first to need this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find anything on Scheme in general. You'll need to focus on the implementation you happen to be using.

I use Chicken, so here's how you'd do it with that implementation using the http-client module.

```
(import (prefix http-client http:))
(http:with-input-from-request url #f read-string)
```

Comment: Thanks. And I know, which is why I did a lot of searching involving terms like "ypsilon" "R6RS" "programming" and excluding all sorts of unrelated things like "-python". Still nothing.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ypsilon having never used it, but didn't the development of that implementation stall years ago? At any rate I think if you want an R6RS implementation then you might try PLT Racket instead since the support for that platform is alive and well.

Comment: As I understand it (and John in the other comment seems to confirm) Racket isn't really meant to be Scheme at all, but rather a different language entirely (why it's then called a Scheme implementation beats me). As for ypsilon, I haven't heard that it's stalled, but apparently it doesn't have a lot to offer besides basic R6RS, which frankly isn't much.

Comment: If you're willing to shop around a bit might I suggest one of either Chicken, Gambit or even Common Lisp? The first two are R5RS implementations and are quite nice. Chicken probably has the bigger / more active community. The difference Common Lisp platforms are nice when you want portability across implementations and can afford the typically larger runtimes that they come with.

Comment: I'd like to avoid R5RS implementations. I started out with guile but switched to ypsilon for that reason. I've considered Common Lisp, but I haven't been able to tell if it's more standardised than Scheme. I think clojure seems nice at a glance, though; I like that it apparently integrates well with Java.

Comment: Well, CL is at least an ANSI standard and has a "more batteries" included philosophy, if only slightly more so compared to Scheme. The bigger benefit I think for you is that there's a pretty large set of libraries out there that are (usually or often) portable between implementations...Clojure sounds like it could be a good fit for you, but it never settled well with me personally. Mostly I think because I view the JVM as baggage I don't want. Sounds like that could be a bonus for you though.

Comment: Perhaps I'll look into both. Easier to make a choice that way. Thanks for your help, either way.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked for, but here's the Racket code required to fetch a website's text:

```
#lang racket

(require net/url)

(define website-text
  (regexp-match 
   #px".*"
   (get-pure-port (string->url "http://planet.racket-lang.org/"))))
```

Also, it may help you to regard Scheme as being a family of languages, rather than a single language; many implementations differ dramatically from the RnRS standards.

Comment: Thanks. And that's why I'm starting to learn to dislike Scheme, despite everything else.

Comment: I don't know if I'd like to turn to some "fringe" language. Also seems odd to me to call it a Scheme implementation if it's not meant to be Scheme at all. I really like standards and Scheme seems to suffer greatly in that area. I think I may have to switch to some other form of Lisp. Clojure seems potentially nice at a glance.

Comment: Ah! You said the magic word! Clojure is a LISP implementation in a very similar way that Racket is a Scheme implementation. Put differently: if you don't object to Clojure, there's no good reason to object to Racket.

Comment: Racket comes off as "Scheme, but not really" while Clojure comes off as "Clojure (inspired by Lisp)". At least that's the impression. It's kinda like how Java was inspired by C/C++ yet Java is Java. Also, I could go learn INTERCAL too. It wouldn't be very useful aside from the pure experience, and maybe with INTERCAL that experience would be worth it, but in the case of Racket I might as well get that exact same experience from something more "mainstream". So, if my objective is to learn some form of Lisp, I'd go with one of the three major dialects, not Racket.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply.  Obviously, Racket is still working to define itself as a separate entity.

Comment: No problem. Things take time, but for now I just don't think either Scheme or Racket is the right choice for me. But thanks for your answer either way.

Answer (score 0):

guile has a www module, probably PLT/Racket too, but nothing in the SRFIs.

Comment: I see. Sadly guile doesn't support R6RS, or I'd use it instead. I found the source for the www module and tried picking out just the parts I need, but that's easier said than done. Also probably would need some work to get it to work with ypsilon.